# Correct approach to Django Many to Many save

Tags: python, django

Given the models

```
class Book(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   price = models.FloatField()
   inventory_quantity = models.IntegerField()

   def movement(type, qty):
      # ...
      if type == 'sell':
         self.inventory_quantity -= qty
      if type == 'donation':
         self.inventory_quantity += qty
      # ...

class Operation(models.Model):
   operation_type_choices = (
       ('sell', 'Sell'),
       ('donation', 'Donation'),
   )
   book = models.ManyToManyField(Book, through = 'BookOperation') 
   operation_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=operation_type_choices)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(Operation, self).save(*args,**kwargs)
       bok_op = BookOperation()
       bok = Book()
       op = Operation()
       bok.movement(op.operation_type, bok_op.quantity)

class BookOperation(models.Model):
   book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
   operation = models.ForeignKey(Operation)
   quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

On the OPERATION model, i overrode the `save()` function to change the Book quantity by executing the `movement()` function on Book's model(at least that was the intention).
The logic that determines if the inventory_quantity should add or subtract is in this function, is that the right way to do it?

Also, I know my code is extremely wrong on terms of how Python deals with objects, when I save an operation on admin panel I get `movment() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)`, why? It seems that i'm passing only `op.operation_type, bok_op.quantity`

Thanks for the help

Comment: `.movement(type, qty)` should be `.movement(self, type, qty)` because it's an instance method

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly clear on why you're overriding `save`, but you should make the `super` call *last* there, since it's what does the actual saving of the instance data.

Re "takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)", the definition of the `movement` method in the `Book` class should take `self` as its first argument. All Python method calls automatically are passed the instance itself as the first method parameter.

See the Python docs for more: ["the method function is declared with an explicit first argument representing the object, which is provided implicitly by the call..."](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#classes)

(Also, you don't show us where `liv` is defined so we can't be sure what it is -- from reading your code it seems it should be `self` instead.)